# Can a webhook server have no response?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow implementation using Google assistant, a nodeJS server to serve the webhook calls. Some of the user intents are empty phrases, and they do not need any response from webhook server. However, the webhook must be called with every user sentence.

Can the webhook response return an empty response and not crash while doing so?

The server returns the response in predefined JSON format known to google assistant. When I set this response to NULL OR when I set the payload part of this response to BLANK, the application crashes.

```
var simpleChatResponse = {

"payload": {
"google": {
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "richResponse": {
    "items": [

    ]
  }
}
 },
"outputContexts": [

] 
};
```

Actual results: "myAgent1 is not responding" and the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not send an empty response. As the [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#rich-responses) state:

> The first item in a rich response must be a simple response.